# Show users by "location_user" in laravel-8

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, datatables, laravel-8

I have a problem with showing users based on locations,

My problem is that it displays user only, not the user's associated with the locations

I want the user to show him only the users in the locations it is linked in table (location_user)

> **I know the problem is from location_user', 'location_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id'**
>
> **But I want the link is smart and I don't want to add a column in the user list with the name location_id**
>
> **Because I want multiple locations**

This is data of UsersController.php

```
$data = User::leftjoin('location_user', 'location_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->where('location_user.user_id', auth()->user()->id)
->leftjoin('locations', 'locations.id', '=', 'location_user.location_id')
->where('locations.status', '1')
->select('users.*',)
->orderBy('status', 'DESC')->get();
```

> Tables
>
> **users:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3dID.jpg
>
> **location_user:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KGZN.jpg
>
> **locations:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDbDJ.jpg

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your table structure - there is a **many-to-many** relation between **User** and **Location** via **location_user** pivot table.

If the respective relations are defined on both models like

```php
//User Model
public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Location::class);
}
```

```php
//Location Model
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Then you can write a query to get all users that are associated with the logged in user's locations

```php
$locationIds = auth()->user()->locations->pluck('id');

$users = User::query()
    ->whereHas('locations', fn($query) => $query->whereIn('id', $locationIds)
    /** If you want results to include the currently logged in user
      * remove the below where condition **/
    ->where('id', '<>', auth()->id())
    ->get();
```

OR using conventional anonymous closure functions instead of arrow functions syntax

```php
$locationIds = auth()->user()->locations->pluck('id');

$users = User::query()
    ->whereHas('locations', function($query) use($locationIds){
        $query->whereIn('id', $locationIds);
    })
    /** If you want results to include the currently logged in user
      * remove the below where condition **/
    ->where('id', '<>', auth()->id())
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks Donkarnash, but I did not mean the members, I mean the Users, I updated the post. I apologize for the mistake! I hope we find a solution.

Comment: Yes exactly. 

For example: 'location_user', 'location_user.location_id', '=', 'users.location_id'
.. the data will appear, but I want the link to be smart, and I do not want to add a column location_id in Users table. i hope it is clear.

Comment: @Aqaq Say user with id = 1 is logged in. In the image for location_user, user with id = 1 is associated with 2 locations (location_id: 1,2)  - 2 users (user_id:112,114) are associated with location_id = 1 and two users (user_id: 111,115) are associated with location_id = 2. There are two more users (user_id: 107,113) in location_user. Now do you want logged in user to see only 4 users(user_id:112,114,111,115) or  all 6 users(user_id:112,114,111,115,107,113)?

Comment: Yes. I want to show 4 users only.

Comment: @Aqaq Have updated answer to filter out the currently logged in user from the query. Now if you manually simulate currently logged in user  `$locationIds = User::find(1)->locations->pluck('id');`  & replace `where('id', '<>', auth()->id())` with `where('id', '<>', 1)` and have sample data in database as per the image, and run the query it will give you 4 users.

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation, but did you check code & tables in the post? because your code has no link or definition with users' locations, and we have 3 tables, there must be a connection between them. I hope it is clear.

Comment: @Aqaq After ensuring that eloquent relations are defined on the model classes as in the answer. Have you seeded your database with sample data as per the image attached in your question and run the query? The query works in a way which will give you the output as discussed in comments above. Without actually trying out the solution how will you know whether it solves your issue or not?

Comment: Thank you, the code has been modified: 

$data = User::whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($locationIds) {
$query->whereIn('id', $locationIds);
})
->where('id', '<>', auth()->id())
->get();            

it works now. Currently it is invoking users correctly, but excluding the user itself, is it possible to add that.

Comment: @Aqaq To include the currently logged in user in the results just remove `->where('id', '<>', auth()->id())` from the query. By "the code has been modified" - you mean converting short arrow syntax `fn($q) => ` to traditional anonymous closure `function($q){}`, cause I don't see any other change. And remember to mark the answer as accepted/upvote for benefit of future visitors, if this solves your issue.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, thank you again for everything you’ve done, the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you don't need to associate table "location_user" because your user is associated with only one location, so you have here a MenyToOne relationship you can make it by adding these lines to your models  :

```
class User extends Model
{
    //here
    public function location()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
    }
}

class Location extends Model
{
    //here
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

After that, you can query the members in the locations that are linked to a user by id like this :

```
$user = User::find(1); //get user by id : 1
$location = $user->location // get location associted with user id 1 

$members  = $location->users // get all members  associated with the location of user id 1
```

If the case of the relationship ManyToMany, you still can use the same method just by modifying :

```
  /*
public function location()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
        }
*/
```

by :

```
  public function locations()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Location::class,'location_user');
        }
```

and :

```
  /*
public function users()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(User::class);
        }
*/
```

by :

```
  public function users()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'location_user');
        }
```

After you can merge the members by collection methods : [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections)
Or by using whereHas and orHas

Comment: Thanks Mehdi, but I did not mean the members, I mean the Users, I updated the post. I apologize for the mistake!

Comment: Members in the and of the day are the users in your project so are the same